# shared memory (ipc)in linux

Tags: linux, ipc, shared-memory

Shared memory means one process will create a memory portion oher process can acess.

My question is: how will the other process know the created shared memory `shmid` (i.e `shmid=shmget(key-t ,size , permission);`)?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify: The process that creates the shared memory defines the name and permissions (process of the logged in user).

Basically you create a file:

```
file_descriptor = shm_open("/some.shared.memory", 
                   (O_CREAT | O_RDWR),
                   (S_IREAD | S_IWRITE))
```

Or if it exists you can open it:

```
file_descriptor = shm_open("/some.shared.memory",
                   (O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR),
                   (S_IREAD | S_IWRITE))
```

Thus, the name "/some.shared.memory" is your way to find the shared segment. (Note the flags)

- Have a look here http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html
- Do a Google search on "shm_open example" and you'll find lots of examples.
- The process that creates the file will determine the permissions (owner+group) See the **chown** command and **fchmod** functions which you can call to set the permissions. Also have a look at **umask**.

Answer (score 0):

They need to use the same way to derive the key_t; usually you use the `ftok` function where both sides use the same file name and id value, so they end up with the same key.